# Changing a for loop's previous entry

Tags: python, for-loop, iteration

Is it possible to change a for loop, after it has ran and then on the next iteration go back and change it?

```
#the code example
score = 50
running = True
while running:
    for rounds in range(0, 6):
        for rounds in range(0, 6):
           if input() == x:
           score - 3
           print(score)
         elif input() == y:
           score - 2
           print(score)
         elif input() == z:
           score - 1
           print(score)
         elif input() == **change**:
            #Edit previous loop input because of an error or typo(x should have been z previous iteration) #How would one make this happen?
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by changing the loop?

Comment: I can't quite understand your question. But one thing that is wrong is that you are reusing the variable `rounds` in the inner loop. You should use a different name for that one.

Comment: There's no way to undo it. If you ran the code, it has happened. The best thing is to just check for typos before running and doing tests.

Comment: I would like for the input to change the score, decreasing it as we go through the loops. But if the previous input from the previous loop was wrong, it could change it in the current loop. I received an answer which stated that I could just add the the same amount to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think Loop can be turned back one or few iterations. Problem is with the number of iterations you want it to go back.
Though Your use case can be achieved with reversing the operations, you are doing.

```
#the code example
score = 50
running = True
while running:
    for rounds in range(0, 6):
        for rounds in range(0, 6):
           if input() == x:
           score - 3
           print(score)
             elif input() == y:
               score - 2
               print(score)
             elif input() == z:
               score - 1
               print(score)
             elif input() == undoX:
               score + 3
               print(score)
             elif input() == undoY:
               score + 2
               print(score)
             elif input() == undoZ:
               score + 1
               print(score)
```

Crude way of achieving it would be undoX(One operation reversal), undoX2(Two operation reversal) etc. Further datatype of input() is not known; if it is Integer than 'undoX' can be replaced by '-x'.
If you want to keep number of iterations intact after undo operation than change range(0,6) to range(0,iterations) and write in modified cases;

```
            elif input() == undoX:
               score + 3
               iterations+1 //To keep no. of iterations intact with every undoOperation
               print(score)
```